# Stored procedure inserts multiple duplicate rows

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertAttendanceDetail] 

@ConstituentIdNo nvarchar(15),
@AttendanceID nvarchar(15)


AS
BEGIN

   INSERT INTO tblAttendanceDetail (AttendanceID,ConstituentIdNo)
   VALUES (@AttendanceID,@ConstituentIdNo)

END
```

I execute the stored procedure using vb.net script:

```
 For Each id As Object In Arguments.SelectedValues
 Using sql As New SqlProcedure("spInsertAttendanceDetail")
 sql.AddParameter("@ConstituentIdNo", constituentIdNo)
 sql.AddParameter("@AttendanceID", attendanceID)
 sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
 End Using
 Next
```

If I select three records from multiple select grid, it inserts 9 records and if i select four it inserts 16 records with four the same value. Is there any way i can insert record based on how many record i selected let's say if i select three records from the grid then it should only inserts three records as well? Thanks.

Comment: Issue is not in SQL side. How many records you have in Arguments.SelectedValues?. BTW you'd better to move "using" section where you create a procedure, out of your loop, create SqlProcedure then populate the parameters and execute inside the loop.

Comment: looks like you wrote that FOR loop in event handler which is triggered on each row

Comment: @Flicker thanks for the reply and suggestion. There are about 9,000 records in my grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your procedure:

```
   MERGE tblAttendanceDetail as target
   USING (SELECT AttendanceID,ConstituentIdNo 
            FROM (VALUES (@AttendanceID,@ConstituentIdNo))
            as t(AttendanceID,ConstituentIdNo)) as source
    ON targer.AttendanceID = source.AttendanceID 
        AND target.ConstituentIdNo = source.ConstituentIdNo
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT VALUES (source.AttendanceID,source.ConstituentIdNo)
```

It will help you from duplicate data.

But as @FLICKER say in his comment, you should:

> create SqlProcedure then populate the parameters and execute inside
>   the loop

Maybe this will help (vb.net):

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Arguments.SelectedRows
    Using sql As New SqlProcedure("spInsertAttendanceDetail")
    sql.AddParameter("@ConstituentIdNo", row.Cells(0).Value)
    sql.AddParameter("@AttendanceID", row.Cells(1).Value)
    sql.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
Next
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. It fixes the problem, but in the same way "headache" can be healed by amputation of the head. Rather find out WHY the problem occurs and then fix the source.

Comment: Does not answer the question, but fixes part of a problem :)

Comment: Yes, Let's make sure we turn a technical Q&A site into a free code writing service.